# Is there any Radeon drivers for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

So, today I installed Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS to my server, model Dell Precision T7600, it has 2 intel xeon CPU and AMD RX 5500XT GPU installed myself, for mining. I tried to install the latest driver, for ubuntu 20.04, but it started messing up with system boot so I removed it.
When I check installed GPU by terminal code: `sudo lshw -c video`, it shows me this:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=640,480
       resources: irq:59 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:7000(size=256) memory:d3900000-d397ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

It says that there is already a AMD driver, but default driver. Also, in Settings, in page About, it says the GPU is llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits). I never used any linux-based systems, so sorry if I will say something incorrect. Waiting for any info about this from you.

Comment: You don't need any drivers.

Answer (score 5):

have upgraded today 29 april to 22.04 LTS, and "additional drivers" section does not list any proprietary drivers yet. it will take some until they are avaiable; you can also check on the dedicated page for your card here https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-xt will be updated to 22.04 probably soon.

Comment: It never will arrive. There are no 3rd party drivers for amd for Linux. Has been so for a couple of years now.

Comment: ok, thx for your response

Comment: its probobly coming in the next amdgpu-pro release, they are released quartely

Comment: There is now a download for Ubuntu 22.04 but it just enables a https://repo.radeon.com/ repo.